# Replace all characters other than english letters and numbers to underscore

Tags: ruby, regex, ascii

I have a string, and I would like to replace all special characters with underscores.

In other words, I just want 26 english letters (lower and upper cases) and 0-9 and the "_" character.

Also note that there are the non-english characters and they need to be replaced with "_" as well.

What is the most elegant way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: it's basics, you can easily find this [in docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Metacharacters+and+Escapes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you want to replace all non-word characters with underscores. Therefore,

```
result = subject.gsub(/[^\w]/, '_')
```

But are you okay that this would also replace newlines and other whitespace characters?

If not, change it to

```
result = subject.gsub(/[^\w\s]/, '_')
```

**Explain Regex**

```
[^\w\s]                  # any character except: word characters (a-
                         # z, A-Z, 0-9, _), whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                         # \f, and " ")
```

**Note**

As @CarySwoveland mentions, the `[^\w]` can also be written with the shorthand `\W`.

Comment: You could use `\W` rather than `[^\w]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, you're right. For the OP's benefit I tried to make as few changes as possible from one line to the next line. Added it as a note, it's a good idea to mention it, thank you. :)